Analyzing harmony

I'm trying to analyze this simple exercise from schubert but i can't really find the harmonic function here beside the satisfying voice leading that i hear when i play it
I wanna write such a piece but i'm not sure my analyze is correct
Does he use a tonicization and a tritone substitution in measure 8 and 9? And why doesn't he resolve it to ( A )
And why does he use a sharp in the Treble and flat in bass why didn't he just use flats in both cleffs
In measure 3 does the E#  state as a augmented chord?  And if it is
What is it's harmonic function with the other ones

When you see a sharp and flat in the same chord, your first thought could (and probably should) be "augmented 6th chord". Also I6/4 is often viewed as having dominant function - so much that it's more often written V6/4 these days.

Oh that literally tells everything about it it must be a german 6 then

So it's an augmented 6 and a 6/4 cadence eventually

Yeah, Ger6+ and the Neapolitan chord are both basically the classical/romantic/functional concepts that became or were reinvented as tritone subs in jazz. When you see a tritone sub but want to talk about it in a classical context, I suggest looking for augmented 6ths and Neapolitan chords, or bII.

m. 3: The E# does form an augmented chord, and its harmonic function is to lead to the following IV chord, which is a typical use of augmented triads: to move from I to IV. However, it would be equally justifiable to simply label it as a chromatic lower neighbor, making the analysis consistent with the preceding measure.
mm. 8-9: This is a Ger6+, built on b6 of the target key (D major) and leading to a predominant 6-4 chord, which is the typical use of an augmented sixth chord: build on b6 and resolve to V (or V64, in this case).

Thanks for the info but i think the ger6+ doesn't actually resolve to V64 ( as my friend says in the other comment ) it resolves into a I64 that has a dominant function

@user98606 I64 and V64 are two different notations for the same thing. Sometimes C64 (Cadential 6-4) is used to avoid confusion.
